# 3D view not opening in KiCAD - OpenGL error

Tags: kicad, 3d

I am not able to open the 3D view in KiCAD. It is showing this error: "your OpenGL version is not supported. Minimum required is 1.5".

I tried to search the error online and tried to download OpenGL but nothing is happening. Kindly help me out with this issue or finding a link to download the precise openGL.exe file.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `tried to download the openGL but nothing is happening`

Comment: please stop assuming that we know what you have, and what you are doing

Comment: An error message like that is often linked to old graphics card drivers. I never had to install OpenGL separately. Or your GPU is too old to run OpenGL 1.5, which would be a card from before 2003.